# Dropdown menu - disappear after clicking on item

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to create "dropdown menu" in React. I've used `useState` inside functions in `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave` events (in *dropdown-holder-us* `div` / **NaviMain**), to toggle `display` of "dropdown menu". Last thing is to make "dropdown menu" disappear , when clicking on **DropdownMenuItem**. Could someone hint me how to achieve this?

**App.js**

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import NaviMain from "./components/NaviMain";
import Info from "./pages/Info";
import VerticalAlign from "./pages/VerticalAlign";
import Flexbox from "./pages/Flexbox";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <NaviMain />
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Info />} />
            <Route path="/verticalalign" element={<VerticalAlign />} />
            <Route path="/flexbox" element={<Flexbox/>} />
          </Routes>      
        </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**NaviMain.js**

```
import { useState } from "react"
import DropdownMenuItem from "./sub-components/DropdownMenuItem"

const NaviMain = () => {

    const [disp, setDisp] = useState("hide-menu");

    const hoverOn = () => {
        setDisp("show-menu")
    }

    const hoverOff = () => {
        setDisp("hide-menu")
    }

  return (
    <nav>
        <ul">

            <li onMouseEnter={hoverOn} onMouseLeave={hoverOff}>
                <a className="hover-pointer">school</a>
                <div className={`dropdown-holder-us ${disp}`}>

                    <DropdownMenuItem title="v align" link={"/verticalAlign"}/>
                    <DropdownMenuItem title="flexbox" link={"/flexbox"} />

                </div>
            </li>           
        </ul>    
    </nav>
  )
}
export default NaviMain
```

**DropdownMenuItem.js**

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
    
const DropdownMenuItem = ({title , link}) => {    

  return (
    <>
      <Link to={link}">
        {title}
      </Link>   
    </>   
  )
}
export default DropdownMenuItem
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After rebuilding **NaviMain.js** (like @cSharp suggested in his answer), Ive created separate components **DropdownMenu** (containing logic) and **MenuItemContentSchool** (with content). So the "`hover`" effect, managed by mouse evenets, is in `li` - which is a parent for "DropdownMenu". And the desired disappearance of "DropdownMenu" is managed by click event, inside the container `div`. Quite simple, inspired by [Brian Design](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T2MhVxJxsL0) video.

**NaviMain.js**

```
import { useState } from "react"
import DropdownMenu from "./DropdownMenu";

const NaviMain = () => {

    const [disp, setDisp] = useState(false);
    const hoverOn = () => setDisp(true)
    const hoverOff = () => setDisp(false)
    

  return (
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li className= onMouseEnter={hoverOn} onMouseLeave={hoverOff}>
                <a>school</a>
                { disp && <DropdownMenu /> }
            </li>          
        </ul>
    </nav>
  )
}
export default NaviMain
```

**DropdownMenu**

```
import { useState } from "react"
import { MenuItemContentSchool } from "./sub-components/MenuItemContentSchool"
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const DropdownMenu = ( {disp} ) => {

  const [click, setClick] = useState("")

  const handleClick = () => {
    setClick("hide-menu")
  }


  return (
    <div className={`dropdown-holder-us ${disp} ${click}`}>

    {MenuItemContentSchool.map((item, index) => {
      return (
        <Link to={item.link} className="d-content-us" onClick={handleClick}>
          {item.title}
        </Link>
      )
    } )}

</div>
  )
}
export default DropdownMenu
```

**MenuItemContentSchool**

```
export const MenuItemContentSchool = [
    {
        title:"v align",
        link:"/verticalAlign"
    },
    {
        title:"flexbox",
        link:"/flexbox"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think easiest solution is to make `disp` a boolean which decides whether the dropdown menu is shown or not. I have shortened the dropdown menu to a `<DropdownMenu>` component for better legibility (you might want to do this in your code to, might be easier to maintain).

```
const NaviMain = () => {

    const [display, setDisplay] = useState(false);

    const hoverOn = () => {
        setDisplay(true)
    }

    const hoverOff = () => {
        setDisplay(false)
    }

  return (
    <nav>
        <ul">

            <li onMouseEnter={hoverOn} onMouseLeave={hoverOff}>
                <a className="hover-pointer">school</a>
                {
                    display ? <DropdownMenu / >
                }
            </li>           
        </ul>    
    </nav>
  )
}
```

If it is difficult to make dropdown menu appear and disappear like this,
another way to make it work is to attach `disp` to a css class which decides if `DropdownMenu` is `display: block` or `display: none`.

Comment: `disp` is currently managing CSS classes (`display : block/none`). Your code is cleaner and more elegant for making menu "on/off" on hover, but that still doesn't solve hiding menu when "menu item" clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar problem, then i found the RCA.

**My Page Structure when error was reproduce.**

```
function Parent(){
   const [state,setState] = useState([]); // store multi-select state
   function MultiSelect(){  // placement of this function is problem

   }

}
```

`When state of multi-select changes then parent component is redrawn so memu item disappear.`

**My Page structure Post fixing of structure**

```
function Parent(){
   const [state,setState] = useState([]); // store multi-select state
  

}
function MultiSelect(){  // placement of this function outside parent

}
```

> My Placement of multi-select component declaration inside parent
> component was creating problem, when state of parent was updated
> multi-select component was redrawn